# using c++11 inside a c# program

Tags: c#, c++, c++11, interop

I am programming some graphical filters in my main program which is based upon C#. 
However C# is not fast for getpixel / putpixel.
I've seen workarounds for it, using unsafe code in C#
 
Unsafe code gives me a bit an unsafe feeling too, as i understand the benefit of safe code and memory cleanup.

So now i am wondering....
 
Might it be better to write this unsafe code in a separated dll based on C++ ?.
However I never made mixed language programs, so i am wondered.

- How would one pass a bitmap from C# to a function in a C++ 
  i can set the reference to the dll, but i dont think that will be enough
- How would one pass some returned values and the bitmap back again to the c# main program

Also what if i used another compiler to write the c++11  .dll would that be a problem?
The main program is written in visual studio 2010 expres

Comment: Use C++/CLI. Directly callable from C# and no ugly unsafe hacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use C++ then you also can use C# with unsafe code. Both is unsafe and in C# you still don't need to care about memory cleanup. The only thing you have to care about is accessing invalid pointers which will cause a `AccessViolationException`.

```
public unsafe void SwapChannels(Byte[] imageSrc)
{
    fixed (Byte* pImageSrc = imageSrc)
    {
        // Swap channels here
    }
}
```

I'm using unsafe code in my image libraries too. If you are not going cross-plattform you can also use C++/CLI.

Comment: And C# unsafe code still might end up noticeably slower than C++ code/not noticeably faster than "safe" C# code. Please note might- without measuring it is just a guess fest. :D

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Of course: http://davidthomasbernal.com/blog/2008/03/14/c-image-processing-performance-unsafe-vs-safe-code-part-ii/

Comment: Hm this looks close to i think i'd like it to behave.

Comment: So it doesnt matter if i understand you correctly.
If i would write an external c++ lib it would be as fast 
as c# with unsafe ?. (my filters are simple code will not run cuda GPU basically it will be byte array based)

i like something else here too you wrote in your sample you go from type bitmap to type Byte[] thats nice. is that another thing that comes available by unsafe type conversion ? (with of-course its own risks i understand those)

Comment: @user613326 Depending on which bitmap class you are using, you should be able to lock the bytes and work with them directly at your own risk. I think C++ should be a bit faster but C# is cross plattform and you don't have to use interop. As mentioned, i'm always using unsafe for image processing in my library and i'm happy with it and its fast enough.

Answer (score 4):

Actually I am doing exactly the same you mentioned (graphical filters) using CUDA. To be able to call C functions from managed code (WinForms) I utilize InteropServices.

Let's say you have 2 projects in a solution - C++ library and some C# project.

To declare function in C++ library I use following parameters:

```
extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall cudaCopyInputData
    (int n, int w, int h, byte* data)
{
    inputBuffer = data;
    bufferLength = n;
    inputWidth = w;
    inputHeight = h;
    useFloatBuffer = 0;
    binaryBufferValid = 0;

    int bufferSize = bufferLength * sizeof(byte);
    int floatBufferSize = bufferLength * sizeof(float);
    int binaryBufferSize = w * h * sizeof(int);

    cudaMalloc((void**)&cudaInputBuffer, bufferSize);
    cudaMemcpy(cudaInputBuffer, inputBuffer, bufferSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cudaMalloc((void**)&cudaFloatBuffer, floatBufferSize);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&cudaBinaryBuffer, binaryBufferSize);

    return 0;
}
```

To be able to use it from C# project I import this function as a static method using InteropServices:

```
[DllImport("CUDA Dll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern int cudaCopyInputData(int n, int w, int h, IntPtr data);
```

You are then able to use it from managed code as a standard method.

To pass Bitmap data to the imported method you can use something like this:

```
BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
```

Then pass bmpData.Scan0 as a pointer to bitmap data and some other parameters like Width, Height, Stride or whatever you want to figure out data format in the C function. In the example above you will have 4 bytes for every pixel (3 bytes + 1 dummy byte) so it's comfortable to process it.

To reuse processed data from your bmp object you just call after processing it:

```
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do interop between C++ and C#: C++/CLI, COM and P/Invoke.

C++/CLI and COM have areas in which either one can be better, but I don't think P/Invoke should ever be used, except for some quick-and-dirty solutions.

In your case, especially since you mention that the C++ DLL is built with another compiler, I think COM is your best bet.

But note that using C++ is pretty much like using unsafe code in C#. Pointers all around, for example.

Answer (score 0):

[SWIG](http://www.swig.org) allows you to easily wrap C++ code and expose classes/functions in c#. I used it to expose some of my image processing routines in c# and it's a breeze.You end up with classes behaving as c# classes , the SWIG generated wrappers handle the type conversions (mostly) and the P/Invoke stuff.

The site swig.org is down at the moment i'm writing, if somebody knows why ,please comment

As for the compiler mixup I have good experience with Mingw compiled DLL.

edit: You still can access the [project sourceforge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swig/)